# AngularJS: Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to bind a custom **onchange** handler to the input file element. getting the following error:

**Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: setRuleFile(element**

Is there any way to work around it?

Thanks. Here are the relevant excerpts from my code.

html:

```
<input type="file" on-select-file="setRuleFile(element)"/>
```

controller:

```
$scope.setRuleFile = function(element) {
    // Extract selected file name
    var pathArray = element.value.split('\\');
    $scope.data.ruleFileName = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];  // take only name without path
    $scope.data.ruleFile = element;
}
```

directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('onSelectFile', function ($parse) {
    // Triggered when user selects file
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Get callback into variable and bind it to onchange handler
            onSelectFileFunc = $parse(attrs.onSelectFile);
//console.log(onSelectFileFunc(scope, {'element': element}));
            element.bind('change', function() { onSelectFileFunc(scope, {'element': element}); } );
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: why would you ever need element passed to controller? Controllers shouldn't know anything about the dom. Also you already have element exposed in directive. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @charlietfl: how do I extract filename then? Also after that I will need to use file reader: var reader = new FileReader(); reader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.data.ruleFile.files[0]); and, as you see from my code, $scope.data.ruleFile = element; If I do not use element, how can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Read all the file data in directive.Use isolated scope to bind  methods or model objects to update. All controller should care about is the data itself

Comment: pass $event instead of dom, and use $event.target in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to write a file upload directive in Angular 1.x:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('fileUpload', fileUploadDirective);

function fileUploadDirective() {
  function postLink(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
    iElem.on('change', doStuff);

    // remove DOM event listener when Angular scope is destroyed
    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      iElem.off('change', doStuff);
    });

    function doStuff() {
      console.log(iElem[0].files);
    };
  };

  return {
    link: postLink,
    restrict: 'A'
  };
}
```

...and you would use it in your HTML template like this:

```
<input type="file" file-upload>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/o0ysyem5/

This directive just uses jqLite (Angular's watered-down version of jQuery) to add a DOM event listener to the element; and the HTML5 [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to get the file object from the element.

### Update

Per the OP's comment, the following is an updated example that shows how to make the file object available to other directives in the same scope.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('fileUpload', fileUploadDirective);

function fileUploadDirective() {
  var postLink = function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
    function updateModel(event) {
      if (iElem[0].files && iElem[0].files.length) {
        var file = iElem[0].files[0];
        ngModelController.$setViewValue(file, event.type);
      }
    };

    iElem.on('change', updateModel);

    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      iElem.off('change', updateModel);
    });
  };

  return {
    link: postLink,
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A'
  };
}
```

...and you would use it in your HTML template like this:

```
<input type="file" ng-model="myFile" file-upload>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/o0ysyem5/3/

This example uses [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), rather than binding the file directly to scope. Doing so enables the user of the directive to decide which variable to store the file object in, via the `ng-model` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not do exactly what I need. I need to have a button select that selects file, and another button, Import, that reads and uploads file to server. The first button is supposed to trigger storing element and file name for display while the 2nd button would use the element to read file (and send it). How would you pass the element from directive to the scope for storage?

Comment: That postLink function gets called with several arguments, including a reference to scope, so you could bind the results to scope in your doStuff function. A better approach would be to require ngModel and update $modelValue via ngModelController...I will post an update later this evening (I'm out of pocket at the moment).

Comment: @jazzblue I have updated my answer to illustrate how to store the uploaded file object as a variable using `ngModel`. Hope that helps!